# In PhP how can i send e-mail to the reciepent

Tags: php

My website is built with PHP. It has a login session and a contact-form. But there is no DB connection available. How could i collect the messages from "contact us" page and send them to my mail?

Comment: ...by [asking Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=contact%20us%20form%20tutorial). There are literally thousands of tutorials out there for this. No-one is going to sit and write another one specially for you.

Comment: PHP has `mail()` function. If that does not work, search for PHPmailer on google and use external SMTP,

Answer (score 2):

```
$to = "someone@example.com";          
$subject = "Test mail";  
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";  
$from = "someonelse@example.com";  
$headers = "From:" . $from;  

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

for more reference you can check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 0):

Php's [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function would allow to do this. However, to save yourself headaches and to be able to create emails with a nice OOP interface, I highly recommend using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

This is a quick example from the manual:

```
  // Create the message
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

  // Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Your subject')

  // Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

  // Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

  // Give it a body
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

  // And optionally an alternative body
  ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')

  // Optionally add any attachments
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'))
  ;
```